# Compress folders with lots of duplicate files

Tags: zip, compression

I have a hierarchy of folders which contain lots of duplicates files (it's a series of versions of a LaTeX document, and while the evolved a lot, many of the figures are identical in multiple versions).

I tried to compress it with Maverick's native “Compress” right-clink menu item, but it doesn't seem to take advantage of the duplication (it leads to 15% compression, though I have at least 30% duplicated files in size).

So I'd wondering: are there common compression formats which would be good enough to take advantage of duplicated files? What app should I use for compression in that particular case?

Answer (score 1):

I use 7zip to handle this and encodings issue. I use it from macrpots/command line, but there're many GUI versions

Comment: As I understand it, 7zip is a tool that supports multiple compression formats. What format do you use, that can handle duplicate file detection?

Comment: I use 7zip format with best compression.

Answer (score 1):

7-zip supports the 'WIM' file format which will detect and 'compress' duplicates. If you're using the 7-zip GUI then you simply select the 'wim' file format.

Only if you're using command line 7-zip, see this answer.
https://serverfault.com/questions/483586/backup-files-with-many-duplicated-files